# Access Store observable array contents and perform function on each item

Tags: angular, redux, ngrx

I am using ngrx for state management. I have a resolver that downloads some data to the store from a firestore database. I would like to take each entry in the array and call a function with it as the input. I have tried a couple of ways to do this, but none work.

```
    this.makDesigns$ = this.DesignEntityService.entities$
        .pipe(
            tap((makDesign) => {
            console.log(makDesign)  // an empty array?
        }))
```

Relevant section of the DesignEntityService

```
getAll(): Observable<makDesign[]> {

    return <Observable<makDesign[]>> this.afs.collection('designs', ref => ref
        .where('status', '==', 1 )
        .where('deleted', '==', false))
        .valueChanges()
```

I am not sure why the results are always an empty array?

Comment: How is the second block related to the first block? From what I can see, you're accessing `this.DesignEntityService.entities`, but second block doesn't have such variable?

Comment: just a simple guess, the pipe doesn't work until you subscribe to `this.makDesigns$`, hope you have a subscription already.